# Modulus Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am watching a tutorial an i saw how to use the modulus they said if 20/7 = 2.8571422857 you must subtract the whole number then multiply it by the divisor

now am trying to understand a Public key encryption example this person said 595^611 mod 899 = 119

i cant see how he got the 119 which is w

is video is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxwmpsRCuqQ

what i did was take 611 divide it by 899 then i got 611 when i raise 585 to 611 as in 595^611 i got math error on my calculator please any one can you assist me how he got to that number are is he wrong? oh if u illustrating cann u use umber that can be process by  calculator

Answer (score 1):

Computing
$595^{611} \mod 899$
is something most calculators
can not do.
First,
they can not even compute
$595^{611}$.
Second, even if they could,
the result would have to be exact,
which, again, most can not do.
Some high-end calculators
by
HP and TI can do this,
and these may even have built in routines
to compute
$a^b mod\ c$.

If you want  do this computation,
you have to program a loop
which gets appropriate powers of
$595$ and gets their remainder
mod $899$.
A simple version would be

$\begin{align}
&a = 595\\
&b = 611\\
&c = 899\\
&ans = 1\\
&for\ i = 1\ to\ b\\
&\quad ans = ans \times b\\
&\quad if\ ans>c\ then \ ans = ans\ mod\ c\\ 
\end{align}
$

For large numbers,
you would do repeated squaring
of $ans$
and multiplying by $a$
using the binary representation of $b$.

All this is very well known.
The subject to look up
is "arbitrary precision arithmetic".

Answer (score -1):

Well, $899=30^2-1=29\cdot 31$ is its prime decomposition. We can solve separately $595^{611}$ both modulo $29$ and modulo $31$.

$595=600-5=20\cdot 30 -5 = 20\cdot 29+20\ -5 \equiv 15 \pmod{29}$, similarly 
$595=20\cdot 31 -20\ -5\equiv -25\equiv 6 \pmod{31}$

The powers modulo a *prime* $p$ are always periodic, with period a divisor of $p-1$. (*Euler-Fermat*: $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ if $a\not\equiv 0\pmod p$.)

So, for the exponents, we have
$611\equiv 23 \pmod{28}$ and $611\equiv 11 \pmod{30}$.

From these, we get
$595^{611}\equiv {15}^{611}\equiv {15}^{23} \pmod{29}$ and $595^{611}\equiv 6^{11}\pmod{31}$.

Now you can start to calculate the powers of $15$ modulo $29$, e.g. $15^2=225\equiv 22\equiv -7 \pmod{29}$, then $15^3\equiv -7\cdot 15 =-105 \equiv -18\equiv 11 \pmod{29}$, $\ 15^4\equiv 11\cdot 15=165\equiv 20$, and so on...

Finally, when you get $595^{611}\equiv x\pmod{29}$ and $595^{611}\equiv y\pmod{31}$, you can find/verify the required remainder modulo $899$.